# How do I get all the values exactly from a serialized json in json.net, c#

Tags: c#, json

Working with Json.NET, c#, .Net 3.5.

Suppose I have the following json:

```
{
  "invoicenr": "315.80042",
  "invoiceid": 3474838,
  "invoicedate": "2017-09-20T00:00:00+02:00",
  "invoicetype": "C",
  "invoicemethod": "I",
  "invoicemailby": "M",
  "amountex": -0.01,
  "amountin": 0
}
```

I need all the values exactly as they appear in this json to form a string containing all those values.

So the result should be

```
"315.8004234748382017-09-20T00:00:00+02:00CIM-0.010"
```

JsonTextReader will not do, because it returns different values:

```
"315.80042347483820-9-2017 0:00:00CIM-0,010"
```

The example json is very simply. In the real world it is much more complex, containing arrays, objects. So the solution should be universal.

Any ideas anybody? Thnx.

Comment: Deserialize your JSON into an object representing that JSON, then concatenate those fields together into a string.

Comment: What is the purpose to concatenating all the values together like this?

Comment: Is this is for some crazy compression algorithm of some sort?

Comment: Thnx, But then I have to do formatting of the fields myself. Or am I missing something? The example json is serialized from an object. I need the exact json representation of the values.

Comment: This is JSON from an object you are _already_ serializing?  And you want this result inside the output JSON?

Comment: The purpose is to calculate a hashcode over all the values. The hashcode is used for security reasons. I has a purpose.

Comment: You will have to clarify what you are asking, right now its very unclear what it is you need.

Comment: Even if the JSON is large you don't have to write the classes yourself. Just get a JSON string which has every possible property filled and use http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Why not just take a hash of the entire JSON fragment?

Comment: Use a real hashing algorithm like SHA1. It achieves the desired result with less maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my first answer because I finally found a much simpler solution. You can use `JsonTextReader`, if you just set a option to not specially interpret DateTime objects. And that's it.

```
public static string GetJsonProperties(string json)
{
    string outputString = "";
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    //don't do date conversion, but get them as their verbatim string.
    reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Value != null)
        {
            //We are not interested in the name of properties..
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                outputString += reader.Value;
        }
    }
    return outputString;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string someJson = 
        "{ "+
        "  \"invoicenr\": \"315.80042\", " +
        "  \"invoiceid\": 3474838, " +
        "  \"invoicedate\": \"2017-09-20T00:00:00+02:00\"," +
        "  \"invoicetype\": \"C\", " +
        "  \"invoicemethod\": \"I\", " +
        "  \"invoicemailby\": \"M\"," +
        "  \"amountex\": -0.01," +
        "  \"amountin\": 0," +
        " \"someArray\" : [1,2,3]," +
        " \"subObj\": { \"a\":42, \"b\":1337} " +
        "}";

    Console.WriteLine(GetJsonProperties(someJson));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Outputs

```
315.8004234748382017-09-20T00:00:00+02:00CIM-0,010123421337
```

Comment: Thnx, I'll have a look at it tomorrow.In XML you have something called innerText, which does exactly what I want for XML.

Comment: @Remco: Found a simpler and universal solution, answer has changed.

Comment: Missed that setting! Thnx, Works like a charm for me.

Comment: @Remco you can mark this answer as correct here then to close the question.